# REST Calls with Http2.0 over Http1.1

Tags: rest, http2

I was reading through HTTP2.0 as new HTTP protocol and advantages with binary header and multiplexing. But i would like to know for Rest calls does migrating from HTTP1.1 to HTTP2.0 provide any reasonable advantage. I am not able to find any specific gain for REST full calls with HTTP2.0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does, in several ways:

- Better support for streaming transfers. The conventional alternative is a combination of HTTP/1.1's chunked transfer encoding, `connection` header Voodoo and the willingness or not of any of the parts to implement HTTP pipelining (which, e.g., curl enables by default). In my experience it takes a lot more of work to get the three to work well together than to just slap HTTP/2. There is no need for chunked transfer-encoding with HTTP/2, and the protocol does not support it.
- With HTTP/2, you can have many requests in flight, REST or not, with zero time for establishing connections. This is a blessing both for the browser and for the server, which has to allocate less files descriptors per client.
- Header compression also applies to HTTP/2 REST requests, together with the associated bandwidth reduction.

So, if in doubt, go always for HTTP/2. There are also excellent tools out there to develop HTTP/2 applications. Some, like ShimmerCat, even remove the drudgery of setting up certificates and DNS alias, so that starting with HTTP/2 from day one becomes a no-brainer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sure I will give it a try myself